# Why does "Copy if newer" not copy a file when the file is updated?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file-io

I have a solution in Visual Studio Express that looks like this:

[image]

The `LogicSchema` class in C# that will parse a specified XML file at run-time. The following is in the `main` method of `Program.cs`:

```
LogicSchema ls = new LogicSchema(
    XDocument.Load(
        "schemas\\C#Schema.xml",
        LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace));
```

I created a folder in my solution called "schemas" to save the XML file and set the Build Action to *Content* and the "Copy to Output Directory" value to be *Copy if newer*.

My expectation is that if open the file in notepad, make a change, and save it, the updated version of the XML file will be copied to the ouput directory (in this case, bin\debug) when I press F5.  However, the updated file is not copied to the output directory unless I select **Rebuild**. Regular **Build** does not work.

What do I need to change so that when I press F5, the file is copied to the output directory when it's been updated?

Comment: Have you tried setting the build action to None?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have tried the same scenario in VS2010 Beta 2 and it works. Seems like a bug in the express edition.

Comment: @Ikaso 2015 Professional still seems to have the same issue.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem for a file with a "Build Action" of "None" - how did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to work also in Visual Studio 2008 Team System - 
>   must be Expression edition specific, so cannot repro...

OK, my original guess was not true - it is about XML file being in the referenced library. Can repro it now.

I think the most natural way would be to embed the XML as resource and then read it with `GetManifestResourceStream()`. This way, the XML file would follow your dll as you reference it without copying it separately even if you reference the dll directly and not through project reference.

...or then you could use Pre-build event? (Project properties - Build Events):

```
copy $(ProjectDir)test.xml $(SolutiontDir)projectFolder\bin\debug\test.xml
```

I would think it will always run even if VS thinks no source files have changed. At least in full VS2008 this is the case - just tested.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that the "schemas" folder is part of *LogicParser*, whereas Program.cs, the class from which `LogicSchema` is being instantiated, is in *LogicParser.ConsoleApp*.

Comment: True: I was too lazy to do the separate class library when I tested this. Did it now and it happens in the full version of Visual Studio as well. So not Expression edition specific.

So I suppose your options are to add the pre-build event with $(SolutionDir) or then embed the xml as resource and read it with GetManifestResourceStream(). 

I think the latter is better - if you are creating a dll, it would be nicer if you can use it by referencing it without adding other (xml) files.