# Refreshing DataGrid View With From Access DB File

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, refresh

So, I've got a simple application that needs to view, insert, update, and delete data from an access db file by using the DataGrid tool in Visual Studio 2012. Upon initial load, my database loaded fine, and to my knowledge it is a bound data source:

I used an Access DB table called lawyers and created a binding data source called lawyerBindingSource attached to my lawyerGridView inside of my LawyerForm.

The problem is that when I relaunch my application, the newly inserted data does not refresh within my GridView. I've read similar stackoverflow questions on this topic, but have yet to find a solution. Please help! Here is my form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NewcomerAndAssociatesSystem
{
public partial class Lawyers : Form
{
    public Lawyers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Lawyers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'seniorProjectDb1DataSet.LawOffice' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.lawOfficeTableAdapter.Fill(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.LawOffice);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'seniorProjectDb1DataSet.Lawyer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.lawyerTableAdapter.Fill(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.Lawyer);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lawyerReturnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new MainForm().Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.lawyerTableAdapter.FillBy(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.Lawyer);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void fillByToolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.lawOfficeTableAdapter.FillBy(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.LawOffice);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void lawyersQueryToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.lawyerTableAdapter.lawyersQuery(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.Lawyer);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void lawyerBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How is the new data being inserted?

Comment: I'm not sure how it will work yet. The user has the capability to insert new data, but I think I'll need to create a button to commit it to the database. If there is a link to point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

When the application is running, then the newly insterted/updated data is displayed correctly?

It's when you shutdown the application the changes are lost?
If so, that's probably because the database is overwritten again.

Check this thread for more info:
[Why does "Copy if newer" not copy a file when the file is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229920/why-does-copy-if-newer-not-copy-a-file-when-the-file-is-updated)

Comment: Not quite; the application never loads the new data to begin with. I've updated the data inside Access, saved it, and refreshed the data sources, but the new data does not appear.

Comment: Are you sure your binding(s) is/are correct?  In your debugger, check if the table is actually filled with records.

Comment: As far as I know, they should be correct, because i haven't been able to insert any new data yet. The only data that is being displayed is the original data from my access file when I started this new project. This is in Visio 2012 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Update TableAdapter Method to save data in Db other than in your grid:

```
 this.lawOfficeTableAdapter.Update(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.LawOffice);
 this.lawyerTableAdapter.Update(this.seniorProjectDb1DataSet.Lawyer);
```

Comment: Which method would this go in? I've see this procedure, but I'm not sure where to paste it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to paste it in an event that you use to save data. If you haven't used it yet, you can put it for exepmple in  UserAddedRow Event.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying..How do I create an event like that? If I try to do this through the events portion of the solution explorer it says 'Invalid Entry.' I really appreciate the help you are giving me! I'm sorry for being so oblivious, but I'm not really a programmer. This is just a final project to get my degree which wont involve coding